# write formula of regression in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, latex, mathjax

I want to write a mathematical formula along my text that includes alpha and beta values. How can I do so? If I copy paste the formula of **polynomial linear regression** from wikipedia to my code, I get this:

```
{\displaystyle y=\beta _{0}+\beta _{1}x+\beta _{2}x^{2}+\varepsilon .\,}
```

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#:~:text=In%20statistics%2C%20polynomial%20regression%20is,nth%20degree%20polynomial%20in%20x.&text=For%20this%20reason%2C%20polynomial%20regression,case%20of%20multiple%20linear%20regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20polynomial%20regression%20is,nth%20degree%20polynomial%20in%20x.&text=For%20this%20reason%2C%20polynomial%20regression,case%20of%20multiple%20linear%20regression).

I read that there's a library 'react-mathjax' but I couldn't figure out how to use alpha beta symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check out a new library called [`better-react-mathjax`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax) that I have written. It is written with the latest standards of React in mind.

The following code accomplishes what you want:

```
<MathJaxContext config={config}>
  <h2>MathJax use with Latex</h2>
  <MathJax dynamic>
    {"$$y=\\beta _{0}+\\beta _{1}x+\\beta _{2}x^{2}+\\varepsilon$$"}
  </MathJax>
</MathJaxContext>
```

I don't know for what you wanted to keep the last part (`.\,`) so I removed it but you can put it back if you want to.

I have prepared a sandbox for you, check it out and hope you like it!

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/user-example-1-zu5vb